# Unable to get PhpMyAdmin with MariaDb docker-compose

Tags: docker, phpmyadmin, docker-compose, mariadb

Being new to Docker for the purpose of practicing I have created `docker-compose.yml` file on my local environment but I am having issue with PhpMyAdmin it comes up with a wierd error

> mysqli_real_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed:
>   Name or service not known

As far Ive searched for it I have come to know that its due to that PhpMyAdmin is unable to find the server. But unable to fix it.

```
version: '3'
services:
  myapp:
    image: 'bitnami/codeigniter:3'
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    volumes:
      - '.:/app'
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
  mariadb:
    image: 'bitnami/mariadb:10.3'
    environment:
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
  phpmyadmin:
      image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
      container_name: phpmyadmin
      restart: always
      ports:
          - 8080:80
      volumes:
          - /sessions
      links:
          - mariadb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a closer look at the [documentation for the phpmyadmin image](https://hub.docker.com/r/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/).

PhpMyAdmin is configured to connect to a database server named "db".  Alternately, you can provide an explicit hostname by setting the `PMA_HOST` environment variable.

Somewhat separately, you should stop using `links` in your `docker-compose.yml`. This feature is deprecated, and has been replaced by a Docker-maintained DNS service that allows you containers to refer to eachother by name.

With all of the above in mind, you compose file should look something like:

```
version: '3'

services:
  myapp:
    image: 'bitnami/codeigniter:3'
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    volumes:
      - '.:/app'
  mariadb:
    image: 'bitnami/mariadb:10.3'
    environment:
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
  phpmyadmin:
      image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
      restart: always
      ports:
          - 8080:80
      volumes:
          - /sessions
      environment:
        PMA_HOST: mariadb
```

Instead of setting `PMA_HOST` you could also just name your mariadb container "db":

---

You'll note I've made a couple of additional edits to your compose file:

- I've removed the `containername` setting from your `phpmyadmin` service. Setting explicit container names is usually not necessary and will prevent you from running multiple instances of this compose file.
- I've removed the `depends_on` from your `myapp` service, because it is very rarely useful: while it will cause your `myapp` container to start after your `mariadb` container, Docker doesn't actually know whether the database is actually up and running and ready to service requests, so it's still possible that your app will start before the database is actually available.

  The best solution is for your application to retry failed database connections.